# Is fasting for two days dangerous?

Tags: food, metabolism, intermittent-fasting

I've always wanted to try a fast for 1 - 2 days (but with water!) for religious purposes, but I'm always scared it may result in a slowed metabolism or some sort of health problem.

Will a 2 day fast impact the metabolism of an otherwise healthy person?  When I start eating will I begin gaining weight rapidly?  What else should I be concerned about?  I'm having difficulty finding a definitive answer on the net.

Comment: Questions relating to general nutrition are off-topic as stated in the [faq].

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition

Comment: @Chris Nice thought, but I think it will just be a debatefest.

Answer (score 0):

It won't if you're healthy, but it would be up to a doctor to determine if you are.